# How many CD only drives are still around?

Tags: dvd, compatibility, compact-disc

I want to get a pocket CD to keep in my wallet with a live OS so I can get "my own personal computer" on any pc I use, and I just wanted to know if I would be able to go with pocket DVDs or pocket CDs. I want it to be able to be as compatible as possible, so I just wanted to know how many computers are still out there that have cd drive that cannot read dvds?

Comment: @kino Please wait for community consensus the next time before going amok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not be able to maintain files between OS sessions if you run from a CD. You should look at putting an OS on a USB flash drive since USB is pretty universal. Heck, USB stands for Universal Serial Bus. And further in line with your question, no one can really answer that for you. I would think that in places that use really old computers, you would be out of luck in using a CD. For example, maybe libraries or schools or some charities. But then again, the cost of maintaining and trying to get old equipment far outweighs the cost of buying new equipment (doesn't have to be high-end). Hence, I would think you'd be hard pressed to find a computer out there that does have the ability to read DVD's.

Comment: +1: USB sticks are more compact, and (unless it is a very cheap USB stick) faster.

Comment: I thought about USB, but are there a lot of computers that can boot from USB? That is why I was thinking CD.

Answer (score 0):

What you require is rather using [Portable applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application), defined as :

> a computer software program that is
>   able to run independently without the
>   need to install files to the system it
>   is run upon

The best site for these is [PortableApps.com](http://PortableApps.com). See also their [Portable App Directory](http://portableapps.com/apps).
You can also use their [PortableApps.com Suite](http://portableapps.com/suite) :

> PortableApps.com Suite™ is a complete
>   collection of portable apps including
>   a web browser, email client, office
>   suite, calendar/scheduler, instant
>   messaging client, antivirus, audio
>   player, sudoku game, password manager,
>   PDF reader, minesweeper clone, backup
>   utility and integrated menu, all
>   preconfigured to work portably. Just
>   drop it on your portable device and
>   you're ready to go.

However, this suite is just a starting point. Today, many products have a portable version in addition to the installed version. You can therefore create yourself on a USB disk/key a collection of useful tools, as do many computer professionals.